# Reflection by a curve

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, symmetry, reflection

Consider point $A(x_1, y_1)$ and a line $y = x.$ After reflecting point $A$ over $y = x$ we get new point, $A'(y_1, x_1).$ Is there general approach to this? Which point we get after refleting it by line $y = mx$? What about $y = mx + b$? What about reflecting any set of points by **any** continuous curve?

Comment: How do you define "reflection by any continuous curve"?

Comment: One can imagine that continuous curve is set of union of infinitely many lines. For example, curve we get after reflecting $x^2$ over $e^x$. Ok, maybe this definition is not good, but I can't explain it better

Comment: If a curve is  "union of infinitely many lines", then you have infinitely many reflections for a single point if you treat any of these lines on equal ground...

Comment: @1b3b circle reflection is well defined. Reflection over a straightline as well.

Comment: Ok, is there formula for basic cases, $y = mx, y = mx + b (b \neq 0)$ and that circle reflection?